# Raising several run time errors in progress 4GL

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to test some AppServer error handling in progress. However, in order to test it I would like a run-time error with num-messages >= 2. How can you generate such multiple errors?

---

Here are some samples of what I am trying to do

```
IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN      
   LogToAppserver().
```

and

```
CATCH e AS Progress.Lang.Error :
    LogToAppserver(e).
END CATCH.
```

where LogToAppserver looks like

```
METHOD PRIVATE VOID LogToAppserver(  ):

    DEFINE VARIABLE locNumErrors AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

    locNumErrors = ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES.

    DO WHILE locNumErrors > 0:
        MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE (locNumErrors).
        locNumErrors = locNumErrors  - 1.
    END.

    RETURN.

END METHOD.

METHOD PRIVATE VOID LogToAppserver( INPUT iError AS Progress.Lang.Error ):

    DEFINE VARIABLE locNumErrors AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

    locNumErrors = iError:NumMessages.

    DO WHILE  locNumErrors >0:

        MESSAGE iError:GetMessage(locNumErrors ).

        locNumErrors  = locNumErrors - 1.

    END. 

    RETURN.

END METHOD.
```

Comment: Why do you need >= 2 error messages? As long as the code throws an error, that should be enough to test your code.

Comment: Why not create a Progress.Lang.AppError, add some messages with the AddMessage(CHAR,INT) method and throw it?

Comment: @TimKuehn That is the problem of the question, the code is just aimed to display what I try to do. Perhaps you know a way to generate such multiple errors in 4GL or ABL?

Comment: @ArnovanderEnde Sure. This is btw one of most strange things with Progress ABL - one cannot implement the interface Progress.Lang.Error ! What OO is that?

Comment: @AD I never played with that. The documentation say you can create your own ABL error class which inherits from Progress.Lang.AppError

Comment: @ArnovanderEnde Yes, inheritance of AppError is the only way to implement the Error interface. Hence your Error-objects will always have methods like "AddMessage" and "RemoveMessage" (unless you override them with empty code blocks).

Comment: @ArnovanderEnde Another strange Progress thing is that ProError cannot be inherited because it have a private constructor - but then again, Progress.Lang.SysError *do* inherit ProError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
DEF VAR h AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.      

CREATE SERVER h.                  
h:CONNECT("") NO-ERROR.           
DISPLAY ERROR-STATUS:num-messages.
```

It should give 2 messages.